# Log4net won't Register in database using AdoNetAppender MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, log4net, adonetappender

I'm new in log4net logger and I'm trying to create logger using AdoNetAppender to save the logs to a database.

When I use the Simple Layout

```
<conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
```

and for saving to the database:

```
<commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
</parameter>
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
```

It successfully saves to the database; the issue is that i need to register more details (location, method, line) but it fail to save that in the database.

For that I used the following configuration:

```
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
   <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %location 
    %method %line - %message %newline" />
   </layout>
```

And for database inserting:

```
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log( [Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger], 
    [Locaotion],[Method],[Line],[Message],[Exception]) 
                    VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, 
    @logger,@location @method, @line,  @message, @exception)" />
     <parameter>
  <parameterName value="@location" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="255" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%location" />
  </layout>
  </parameter>

 <parameter>
<parameterName value="@method" />
<dbType value="String" />
<size value="255" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%method" />
  </layout>
 </parameter>

<parameter>
<parameterName value="@line" />
<dbType value="String" />
<size value="50" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%line" />
</layout>
</parameter>
```

My C# code :

```
private static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HomeController));
//private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

How can I save the full error details in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the error i was forget a (,) in database inserting code ans i add Application_Error in global

conversionPattern Code:

```
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%location] [%method] [%line] - %message %newline" />
  </layout>
```

database inserting code :

```
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log( [Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Location],[Method],[Line],[Message],[Exception]) 
                              VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @location, @method, @line, @message, @exception)" />
```

and for global code :

```
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MvcApplication));

    private void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

        log.Error("App_Error", ex);
    }
```